# React Native - Cannot animate contentOffset (ScrollView) using Animated.ValueXY

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, react-native, scrollview

I am trying to animate the `contentOffset` of a `ScrollView` using `Animated.ValueXY` in React Native. Currently, the issue I'm having is that the when `.start()` is called, the `ScrollView` does not animate and the `contentOffset` stays at its initial position of `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`

In the docs, for `ValueXY` it outlines the use as:

> 2D Value for driving 2D animations, such as pan gestures

Firstly, is using `ValueXY` to animate the ScrollView an appropriate use? My understanding was that previous to the introduction of this API, you couldn't animate the ScrollView component, but now you can.

If that is correct, here is my usage:

```
this.state = {
  contentOffset: new Animated.ValueXY(), // inits to {x: 0, y: 0}
}
```

Then as a trivial example, on `componentDidMount`, `.start()` is called.

```
Animated.timing(
  this.state.contentOffset, {
    toValue: { y: 1000, x: 0 },
    duration: 5 * 1000,
  }
).start();
```

Lastly, in the render method:

```
<AnimatedScrollView
  onScroll={this.handleScroll}
  contentOffset={this.state.scroll}
  scrollEventThrottle={150}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleStartPress(false)}>
      <Text style={[styles.content, textStyles]} ref='text'>
        {content}
      </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>

</AnimatedScrollView>
```

Comment: Just a quick glance, but shouldn't the AnimatedScrollView's `contentOffset` be `this.state.contentOffset`, not `this.state.scroll`?

Comment: It should indeed be this.state.contentOffset, but it still doesn't work. 

Doesn't appear that contentOffset is animatable. That seems to be restricted to styles, though the implication is it could apply to any simple value. Here is the author's bug report https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9231